# What kind of wire this is in my ceilling

Tags: wiring

There are 3 black and 4 white wires. We found it in our 2nd floor condominium ceilling when cutting holes for lights.

Is black wire power line from meter to breaker panel ? These homes were built around 1988. I tried checking with no-contact voltage tester but it did not beep.

Can someone tell me what kind of wires are these?

[image: wires]

Comment: The  black ones look like coaxial cable. ( Data,TV, Internet )  Not enough info on the white ones. Speaker, or low voltage/

Comment: If you examine the cables closely, there should be identifying text (which may only be imprinted, not colored differently than the jacket, so it can be hard to see) that repeats every 2-3 feet identifying the type of cable. I agree that the black ones have the distinct impression of a braided sheild characteristic of coaxial cable, typically used for either cable television or closed circuit cameras. The white ones look somewhat like telephone or network wiring, but not as distinctly.

Comment: Yes, can you find any printed text on either cable, or any indication about where they lead?

Comment: I would guess they are all coax, installed at different times.  Down vote reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to RG6 being adopted RG 58/59 were common for data (cable tv) most places were updated with RG6 because it is better with modern cable bandwidths. 3 white round cables that were replaced by 3 black round cables, not power most probably RG6 the cable has it’s type and MFG stamped on the side at regular intervals as others have mentioned.